# actix: cannot start server service 0

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have the following main function (CORS is there since I'm using actix to serve a public API):

```rs
use actix_cors::Cors;
use anyhow::Result;
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().wrap(Cors::permissive().send_wildcard()))
        .bind(("localhost", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
        .map_err(anyhow::Error::from)
}
```

It's using [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/), [`actix_web`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/), and [`actix_cors`](https://docs.rs/actix-cors/).

Whenever I run this, an error immideately occurs. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The underlying issue is actually with CORS, specifically, the implicit call made to `Cors#allowed_origin("*")`.

This is probably a bug, but as of now, you can replace it with `::default` and manually call the security laxing that you need:

```rs
use actix_cors::Cors;
use anyhow::Result;
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().wrap(Cors::default().allow_any_origin().send_wildcard()))
        .bind(("localhost", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
        .map_err(anyhow::Error::from)
}
```